# jQuery: How can I remove a div and put it somewhere else?

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="wrapper">
     <div id="example1">
          <div id="navigation">
          </div>
     </div>
     <div id="example2">

     </div>
</div>
```

In the above example, let's say I want to remove #navigation from #example1 and place it in #example2. How can I use jQuery to do that? Do I just use `remove` and `add` or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$("#navigation").appendTo("#example2");
```

Comment: Also `$("#navigation").appendTo("#example2").remove()`